# How to skip to substring in list

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I'm using this:

```
var temp =  conLines.Select((l, i) => new {l, i}).FirstOrDefault(r => (r.l.IndexOf(item.firstParam) >= 0 
     && r.l.IndexOf(item.secondParam) >= 0)
     && (r.l.IndexOf(item.firstParam) < r.l.IndexOf(item.secondParam)
));
```

but I don't want to start "FirstOrDefault" until I first find a certain substring of conLines (a List).

Example:

conLines will look something like so:

```
NAME:

NOTES:

REVISION HISTORY:


format AT 1024 1  4

      1 AC       BUS      ENUM     0030 04    0 0 1/1   632

        NORMAL   04096 1  0,1

      2 AC       BUS-02   ENUM     00C0 06    0 0 1/1   632

        NORMAL   04096 1  0,1
```

and I don't want it to start looking for "FirstOrDefault" until right after the following line, but it's important I still keep track of temp.i in the context of the entire conLines list

```
format AT 1024 1  4
```

I imagine SkipWhile and StartsWith may work but I haven't had any success with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is close. Just add `.SkipWhile(o => o.l!= "format AT 1024 1  4")` before `.FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 1):

`SkipWhile` should work:

```
conLines.Select((s, i) => new {s, i})
        .SkipWhile(si => si.s != "format AT 1024 1  4")
        .Skip(1)         // skip to next line 
        .FirstOrDefault(si => si.s.IndexOf(item.firstParam) >= 0 
                           && si.s.IndexOf(item.secondParam) >= 0
                           && si.s.IndexOf(item.firstParam) < si.s.IndexOf(item.secondParam)
                       );
```

Note that the second `IndexOf` is redundant - if A >= 0 and A < B then B >= 0.

Comment: This will go after Select()? I'm getting an error in regards to applied an operand of type AnonymousType#1

Comment: You may not need `Select`.  I assumed `conLines` was a string collection - if not add the structure to your question.

Comment: Is it possible to keep Select in there? I'm trying to keep track of the index where the FirstOrDefault was found in conLines

Comment: Sure - I'll add it back.

Comment: `conLines` is a string collection. The error happened for whatever reason because I put `SkipWhile` between Select and `FirstOrDefault`